# SSIS package running inside SQL agent won't validate XML Task

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, ssis, xsd

SSIS package flow.

1. has Foreach loop container and enumerate each file in the folder and with variable mapping variable;
2. XML task (inside foreach loop) to validate the XML against XSD;

Input source type is File connection, but under expression I have overwritten "ConnectionString" property to be dynamic.

Output source type is File connection and it is XSD file.

When I run my SSIS package it runs perfectly and validates the file.

The problem occurs when I try to run my package inside SQL Server Agent, it can't validate and it always fails with the following error messages

> There is no Unicode byte order mark.Cannot switch to Unicode

and

> Property "New Source" has no source Xml text; Xml text is either invalid, null or empty string.

But my SSIS package is running and it is able to read source files (xml from the folder) and validates against XSD. But SQL agent can't read my File connection.

I have spend enough time on this and now am bit frustrated and don't want to write another script task to validate.

Edit: I have created SQL Proxy account to run SSIS pacakge, every other package is running fine but validating XML task is not successful.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I suspect either the filename doesn't contain the full path so you are trying to open the wrong file or the credentials are different between the SSIS package and the c# application.  I would not use the mdf filename as part of the connection string.  Instead use the database name in the sql server.  To switch databases you can add 'Use DataBaseName' statement in the query.  The SQL server knows the location of the filename and accesses the mdf file with admin privileges which you don't have when using the mdf filename from c#.